# Cheney garbage collector: Win32 API calls

Tags: c, winapi, memory-management, compiler-construction, garbage-collection

I'm writing a garbage collector for a language and I'm not sure which Win32 API calls I should be using in order to allocate the to- and from-space for Cheney's algorithm. Is the following the correct approach, and if not, what would the correct approach be?

**Initialisation**

Right now I'm thinking `p = q = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dwSize, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE)` in order to allocate the two semispaces, each of size `dwSize/2`. Not sure if I should use `MEM_RESERVE` og `MEM_COMMIT`?

**Allocation**

Whenever an allocation is needed I can then do `VirtualAlloc(q, sizeOfObj, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)` (Assuming that I `MEM_RESERVED` in initialisation) and then increment `q`.

**Garbage Collection**

After moving everything into to-space I can free memory using `VirtualFree(p, dwSize/2, MEM_DECOMMIT)`. Is `MEM_DECOMMIT` the correct approach?

Necessary links:

- [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [VirtualFree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Why reserve contiguous space, but then commit half at a time? Why reserve and commit separately? Why even bother with VirtualAlloc? Why not use malloc or HeapAlloc?

Comment: Garbage collectors should use VirtualAlloc().  There is very little point in making your life complicated with MEM_RESERVE + PAGE_NOACCESS, there is very little point in optimizing a program that uses litte VM, it is already fast.  So just commit.  Only thing you might want to optimize is to not VirtualFree too fast, keep those allocations around for a rainy next few minutes.

Comment: In addition to David Heffernan's comment: LocalAlloc would also be an option. VirtualAlloc would be neccessary if you want to create executable memory pages (for example in a JIT compiler).